# How to check if a variable is an IEnumerable of some sort

Tags: c#, generics, foreach, ienumerable

basically I'm building a very generic T4 template and one of the things I need it to do is say print `variable.ToString()`. However, I want it to evaluate lists and foreach through them and instead print `ListItem.ToString()` My T4 template does not know what type `variable` will be ahead of time, that is why this is so generic.

But my current code that gets generated looks like this:

```
if(variable!=null)
  if(variable is IEnumerable) //error here
    foreach(var item in variable)
      Write(item.ToString());
```

I get a compiler error on the marked line for "Using the generic type System.Generic.Collections.IEnumerable requires one type argument"

I don't actually care what type it is though, I just want to know if you can foreach through the variable. What code should I use instead?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You have already accepted an answer however,since generic `IEnumerable<T>` implements the non generic `IEnumerable` you can just cast to that.

```
// Does write handle null? Might need some sanity aswell.

var enumerable = variable as System.Collections.IEnumerable; 

if (enumerable != null)
    foreach(var item in enumerable)
         Write(item);
else
    Write(item);
```

Comment: This looks like it may be the better answer actually.

Comment: I changed the answer cause I ended up using this method, which in my opinion is much more clean.

Comment: Also, to get around the Mono bug mentioned below, I had to cast `variable` to an `object` first.

Comment: @Earlz: How is this any different from your original `if (variable is IEnumerable)` test? If you want to test for `IEnumerable` then that should work fine for you, assuming that you have the right `using` directive at the top of your source.

Comment: @Earlz: And if you actually need to test for `IEnumerable<T>` rather than `IEnumerable` then this answer is technically incorrect: all `IEnumerable<T>` implementations will implement `IEnumerable`, but not all `IEnumerable` implementations will implement `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @LukeH it is the same - unless `variable` is generic. Which prompts me to make the edit above.

Comment: Keep in mind that String : IEnumerable<char> . This might give some unexpected results.

Answer (score 27):

If you want to test for the non-generic [`IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) then you'll need to include a `using System.Collections` directive at the top of your source file.

If you want to test for an [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) of some kind then you'll need something like this instead:

```
if (variable != null)
{
    if (variable.GetType().GetInterfaces().Any(
            i => i.IsGenericType &&
            i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>)))
    {
        // foreach...
    }
}
```

Comment: @Earlz `System.Collections.Generic` != `System.Collections` -- the error in the post is indicative of not finding the non-generic (IEnumerable) type.

Comment: Heh, I used this and Mono slapped me with `Invalid IL code in EViewEngine.TestView:BuildOutput (): IL_0105: castclass 0x1b000002`  Hmm that's interesting.

Comment: The error occurs with the foreach: `foreach(var item in (IEnumerable<object>)v) __Output.Append(item.ToString())`  looks like I have a bug to report.

Answer (score 20):

The other answers have pointed out the generic/non-generic IEnumerable difference but I should also point out that you will also want to test for String specifically because it implements IEnumerable but I doubt you'll want to treat it as a collection of characters.

Answer (score 10):

Since C# 7.0 you can also achieve this so:

```
if (variable is IEnumerable enumVar)
{
    foreach (var e in enumVar)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Well, somewhat simple but... if you only have:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

you might need to add:

```
using System.Collections;
```

The former defines `IEnumerable<T>` and latter defines `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Thanks for giving the difference, I thought c# has updated and removed IEnumerable.

Answer (score 3):

In *general*, with no non-generic base type/interface, this requires [GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx) and a recursive look-up through the base types/interfaces.

*However*, that doesn't apply here :-)
Just use the [non-generic IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) (`System.Collections.IEnumerable`), from which the [generic IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) (`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>`) inherits.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually test the base class of any generic type directly.

```
instance.GetGenericTypeDefinition()  == typeof(IEnumerable<>)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about object type and you are not in Generic method in C# 7.0+

```
        if (item is IEnumerable<object> enumVar)
        {
            foreach (var e in enumVar)
            {
                    e.ToString();

            }
        }
```

In C# < 7.0

```
        if (item is IEnumerable<object>)
        {
            var enumVar = item as IEnumerable<object>;
            foreach (var e in enumVar)
            {
                e.ToString();

            }
            //or you can cast an array to set values, 
            //since IEnumerable won't let you, unless you cast to IList :) 
            //but array version here 
            //https://stackoverflow.com/a/9783253/1818723
        }
```

Answer (score -3):

This is an old question, but I wanted to show an alternative method for determining if a `SomeType` is `IEnumerable`:

```
var isEnumerable = (typeof(SomeType).Name == "IEnumerable`1");
```

Comment: This won't work, as any specific type of an enumerable will not look like that.  For example, a List<string> would have a name like "List`1".  Also, the number will not always be 1, so you can't assume that either.