# How to set value to an Array field and dictionary using reflection?

Tags: c#

All the values are coming at the run time in terms of string.

```
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class myClass1
    {
        public string obj1;
        public string obj2;

    }
    class myClass2
    {
        public myClass1[] fArray = new myClass1[2];
        public Dictionary<string, string> dictObj = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Type type = Type.GetType("ConsoleApp2.myClass2");
            object myObj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            FieldInfo fi = type.GetField("fArray");

            IList arr = (IList)fi.GetValue(myObj);

            char[] aray = { '[', ']' };
            Type type2 = Type.GetType((fi.FieldType.FullName.Trim(aray)));

            object newObj;
            List<object> mylist = new List<object>();

            {
                newObj = Activator.CreateInstance(type2);
                FieldInfo fi2 = type2.GetField("obj1");
                fi2.SetValue(newObj, "some txt1");
                FieldInfo fi3 = type2.GetField("obj2");
                fi3.SetValue(newObj, "some txt2");
                arr[0] = newObj;

            }
            {
                newObj = Activator.CreateInstance(type2);
                FieldInfo fi2 = type2.GetField("obj1");
                fi2.SetValue(newObj, "some txt1");
                FieldInfo fi3 = type2.GetField("obj2");
                fi3.SetValue(newObj, "some txt2");
                arr[1] = newObj;

            }

    }
}
```

In this way, I am able to pass the value correctly to "fArray". is it the correct way or I can make it more straightforward. 
I would like to know that should I follow the same way for passing the value to the dictionary?

Comment: _"do we need to initialize the array with values before setting the fArray?"_ -- did you try it without doing so? Is there some _specific difficulty_ you're having? It's not at all clear what you're actually asking here. You may or may not need to initialize the array first, depending on how you want the code to be structured. But as a reference type, it certainly _can_ work if you initialize after assignment. What is it you actually need help with here?

Comment: Yes, I want to initialize fArray with some value and then set.

Comment: Have a look at this answer. It solves for the array part and you can use same logic for dictionary: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9783259/13198

Comment: it works for fArray. I have updated the code but still, confuse about the dictionary

Answer (score 1):

If you know it is an array, then it must implement the interfaces of an array including the indexor. Why not simple cast as one of the interfaces. Do you know the types held in the array?

```
IList<T>
ICollection<T>
IEnumerable<T> - does allow setting
```

If you cannot discover T then use

`IList` or `ICollection`

Comment: Thank you with IList it works for the fArray. I have updated the question with the working code for fArray. now I am curious about the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

It's the other way around, use `var array = (myClass1[])fi1.GetValue();` and then just use it as the array it is ;)

Comment: I don't have the information of myClass1[] beforehand I am receiving it at the runtime