# How to check a variable is scalar?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a method to check a variable is scalar type?

scalar variables are those containing an integer, float, double , string or boolean but not array object

thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "scalar"?

Comment: Are you calling a stored procedure ?

Comment: @PaoloTedesco: I guess he wants to know whether a var is elementary or a list(enum, struct)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15374038/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-check-an-executescalar-result-for-existence

Comment: @DanielAbouChleih How do you guess that?

Comment: scalar variables are those containing an integer, float, double , string or boolean but not array object...

Comment: @joe try `!(variable is IEnumerable)` or something similar.

Comment: Joe, your question is not specific enough. There are many more types of variables than the ones you mention.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "scalar", but [`Type.IsPrimitive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isprimitive.aspx) sounds like a good match: it's `true` for `boolean`, integer types, floating point types and `char`.

You can use it as in

```
var x = /* whatever */
if (x.GetType().IsPrimitive) {
    // ...
}
```

For a more granular approach you can use [`Type.GetTypeCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.gettypecode.aspx) instead:

```
switch (x.GetType().GetTypeCode()) {
    // put all TypeCodes that you consider scalars here:
    case TypeCode.Boolean:
    case TypeCode.Int16:
    case TypeCode.Int32:
    case TypeCode.Int64:
    case TypeCode.String:
        // scalar type
        break;
    default:
        // not a scalar type
}
```

Comment: The isPrimitive is containing string?

Comment: @joe: No, but don't take my word for it. Read the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this will always work, but it might be enough for your needs:

```
if (!(YourVarHere is System.Collections.IEnumerable)) { }
```

Or, for checking a `Type`:

```
if(!typeof(YourTypeHere).GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(System.Collections.IEnumerable))) { }
```

Comment: Why not just `!(variable is IEnumerable)` ?

Comment: @joe IEnumerable is the base interface for all enumerable types. An array is enumerable anyway. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590366/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-an-ienumerable-of-some-sort

Comment: @nawfal You're correct. I was thinking of a Type, not a variable. Edited now.

Comment: @joe You're welcome. Note that the first option in the answer you accepted will fail for any "scalar" Type you might declare, and most of the .Net "scalar" types such as `Form`. As for the second - you'd have to add checks for every Type you need to check.(This is assuming I understood you correctly - that you're looking to exclude array's, List's, etc.)